# Using Python to crop an AVI file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pygame

I have a media file (AVI or mpeg doesn't really matter) I'd like to just get the top half of the each frame and remove the lower half from my video. IS there any library in python that can help me?

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend **ffmpeg**. There's a wrapper for python (http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/), though I never tried it.

If that doesn't work, you could just launch a child process for the ffmpeg command-line tool from the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I am experimenting with the Python interface to OpenCV. It is capable of doing real time calculations on the movie stream.